# How to copy text from various Windows controls?

Tags: windows-7

I have Windows program which is in Korean. Now I need to copy the text from different controls in order to translate. This is one of the screens:

[image]

and another example

[image]

Basically there are labels, buttons mostly, some header elements. I remember there was a software to grab a text from UI controls, but can't remember the name.

Comment: [SysExporter](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/sysexp.html) should do the job, but it might not work if the program uses non-standard controls.

Comment: Unfortunately SysExporter doesn't even see the program I am interested, although it doesn't have any security implemented. I even tried to turn on `Display items with invisible parent window`.

Comment: What about [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/)? Or [Strings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897439.aspx)?

Comment: `Resource Hacker` only shows Version Info and Icons. Strings give endless list of strings which I am not able to connect with UI context.

Comment: `Spyxx` will let me go through elements, but still not able to copy the text...

Answer (score 1):

This is not always the easiest of tasks.

I can recommend using AutoIt (http://www.autoitscript.com/site/) and writing a script that saves the text to a file on button click (i.e. gets the text of the control under the mouse cursor).

This is pretty much the function you want:
http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ControlGetText.htm

Here is a nice start guide to reading control text:
http://otland.net/threads/autoit-basics-get-window-text-read-control.17121/

Comment: Ah, when I click the button it may be late :) I guess I had to post it in Stackoverflow...